# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.apache.cxf.service.model.MessageInfo.getFirstMessagePart() org/apache/cxf/service/model/MessagePartInfo;

Tags: spring, maven, cxf

```
cxf-api-2.7.18 - org.apache.cxf.service.model.MessageInfo
cxf-core-3.1.11 - org.apache.cxf.service.model.MessageInfo
```

Both the jars have same class and same package structure.

I am getting

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
    org.apache.cxf.service.model.MessageInfo.getFirstMessagePart()
    org/apache/cxf/service/model/MessagePartInfo;
```

`getFirstMessagePart()` method is available in cxf-core-3.1.11 jar. I have generated the war using Apache Maven 3.3.9 version and deployed it in tomcat server 8. At runtime, looking for the `getFirstMessagePart()` in cxf-api-2.7.18 which is not available. Seems like I have to give cxf-core-3.1.11 jar preference first. How should I do that? Could anyone help me on this?

I am using Java 8 and spring 4.1.7.release

Comment: How did you solve this? I have the same problem. @karthick

Answer (score 1):

Since Apache CXF 3.0 release, core and api module are on the same distribution (cxf-core).

To your problem, you should exclude cxf-api-2.x from your project and use only cxf-core-3.x

Source: [Apache CXF 3.0 migration guide](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/30-migration-guide.html)

Comment: How to achieve this?

Comment: If you are using maven: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#dependency-exclusions

If you are using gradle: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:excluding-transitive-deps

Comment: If I exclude from cxf-rt-bindings-soap (version 3.3.6) cxf-api the exception change into nullPointerException